# apache rewriterule for querystring parameters

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

The code below builds a url in this form.

```
http://mysite.com/browse/department/?pid=1
```

and here is the rewrite cond and rule

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pid=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule browse/(.*)/$ show_products.php?department=$1&pid=%1
```

What i would like is to have 2 extra parameters the first is order buy and the second which isn't necessarily in the url which would be filter so the url would be like this

```
http://mysite.com/browse/department/?pid=1&order_by=a_z
```

or with parameter filter

```
http://mysite.com/browse/department/?pid=1&order_by=a_z&filter=1
```

How do I have my rewrite condition and my rewrite rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the existing query string to your request using the QSA flag (query string append). Since in your case you aren't actually changing the parameters you can do it a lot simpler:

```
RewriteRule browse/(.*)/$ show_products.php?department=$1  [QSA]
```

This will rewrite

```
http://mysite.com/browse/department/?pid=1&order_by=a_z
```

To

```
/show_products.php?department=department&pid=1&order_by=a_z
```

And:

```
http://mysite.com/browse/department/?pid=1&order_by=a_z&filter=1
```

To

```
/show_products.php?department=department&pid=1&order_by=a_z&filter=1
```